# Is it possible to inspect only elements on the screen in iOS?

Tags: java, appium-ios, inspector, appium-android

I write mobile test automation and I got stuck at calendar screen. In iOS app, the calendar is open and show elements of next 12 months. That makes around 500 buttons on that page, when I inspect it.(Only next month on the screen. Around 50 buttons)
It takes to much time to click any element on this screen. As far as I know in Android, inspector only inspects element on the screen. For instance, if you have a very long list, by Android you can only inspect let's say first 20 elements. In contrast, in iOS, you will see 100 elements in the inspector.

Is it possible to tell iOS inspector that just inspect elements on the screen while clicking or doing any gesture?

Comment: Using java or using the inspector?

Comment: I write automation codes in java.  
Inspector is appium ios web inspector.
My aim is to  help automation ro find elements faster.

Comment: My point was there's a difference. Targeting with java will render different performance results than with the inspector. You need an answer strictly from the inspector POV, no matter the language that will be used to write automation. Right? If yes, please edit the question and remove [tag:java] tag